# Currency field display want to use 3-letter ISO code

Tags: visualforce

Currency datatype value is displayed like Rs.100 but I want to show 'INR 100'. Is there a way to change ? I could use decimal and prefix the 3-letter code but want to use currency type if at all possible.

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!saleList}" id="pbt" var="item" style="width:100%;" styleClass="profClass" cellspacing="10px" rowClasses="even,odd" headerClass="hdrClass">
    <apex:column value="{!item.startDateStr}" headerValue="Start Date"/>
    <apex:column value="{!item.totalShares}" headerValue="Total Shares"/>
    <apex:column value="{!item.pricePerShareStr}" headerValue="Share Price"/>
    ...
```

Comment: Multiple currency enabled?

Comment: You could create a custom VF component that displayed the currency fields per your custom spec